# Select attribute value from list-Java

Tags: java, oop

I have a class called `Car`, this class has attributes such as: id, name, price, color and size. When I am creating an object, for color and size I want a list to select the attribute value from. I don't want the user to write "black" or "small", i want to find them somewhere in the app.

```
Car c1 = new Car(1, "Super Car", 152.5, "black", "small");
```

Does anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Maybe you mean that you want to use enum's ?

Comment: you may create enums (`Color`, `Size`) for this purpose

Comment: Please define better your use case, because for example, it is not clear what you mean by "user". Is this a developer that is using your API or the end user that is using your application?

Comment: This is all I did.
`public class Toy {
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Double price;
}
public Toy(Integer id, String name, Double price) {     super();
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.price = price;
}
public Toy(){}
-----
public class Car extends Toy {
private String color;
private String size;
}
public Car(Integer id, String name, Double price, String color, String size) {
super(id, name, price);
this.color = color;
this.size = size;
}      public Car(){}`

Answer (score 0):

You should then have the list of possible values available for the user to pick one. Following is an example for the color (just a simple example, without going too deep into Java constructs for each scenario):

```java
List<String> color = new ArrayList<String>();
color.add("black");
color.add("white");
// etc

Car c1 = new Car(1, "SuperCar", 152.5, color.get(userSelectedOptionIndex), "smal");
```

Here, `userSelectedOptionIndex` should be the index of the option the user chose in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

1) you could use a class  to hold your constants via simple Strings:

```
public final class Constants {

    private Constants() {
        // restrict instantiation
    }

    public static final String COLOR_BLACK = "black";
    public static final String COLOR_WHITE = "white";

    public static final String SIZE_SMALL = "small";
    public static final String SIZE_LARGE = "large";
}
```

Usage:

```
Car c1 = new Car(1, "Super Car", 152.5, Constants.COLOR_BLACK, Constants.SIZE_SMALL)
```

2) another approach is to use enums in Constants class:

```
public final class Constants {

    private Constants() {
        // restrict instantiation
    }

    public static enum Color { White, Black };
    public static enum  Size { Small, Large };
}
```

Usage:

```
Car c1 = new Car(1, "Super Car", 152.5, Constants.Color.White, Constants.Size.Small)
```

3) a yet better approach (more oop approved) is to define enums separately and discard Constants class entirely

```
public enum Color {
    White,
    Black
}

public enum Size {
    Small,
    Large
}
```

Usage:

```
Car c1 = new Car(1, "Super Car", 152.5, Color.White, Size.Small)
```

and in case you if you have a GUI element which users should pick valuse from, it's possible to create an Array or a List with values of these enums and populate your GUI element whith them:

JavaFx 8 example:

```
Color[] values = Color.values();
ComboBox<Color> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.getItems().addAll(values);
```

and later get selected value:

```
Color selectedColor = comboBox.getValue();
```